# Developer error android in app billing v3

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I've implemented iab v3 in my app months ago. It worked fine, now since last week, querying sku details throws a "developer error" on most of our test devices.

So far it only failed on: android version bigger than 4. (eg 4.1.2, 4.2.2, 4.3)

Works fine on 2.3.6

All have the latest available updates from google play/services.

App is not published, it's in development. Beta apk is uploaded to google play.

Anyone else having this problem?
Anyone got any suggestions?

edit:there was a google play services update on the same day my problems started

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://code.google.com/p/marketbilling/issues/detail?id=123&sort=-id&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Google%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary

I just wasted a couple of days, because the sample code had a bug in it. Someone already posted an issue, and it got accepted.
quoting:
"It looks like the version of IabHelper.java distributed with ADT 22 has a problem when querying SKU details as it does not check the number of skus.
If this number is over 20, the billing service returns a developer error (5). Splitting up the request in sets of no more than 20 items avoids it."

I have only 15 in app billing items, but I already owned more than 5, so I went over the 20 limit(the sample code just adds the owned item list to the all item list), for which the code was working, so it had nothing to do with api levels, it's just that my test devices have different acocunts on them, that have different number of owned items.